# Is it possible for Windows' command prompt to display the correct charters when connected to a linux machine via SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, console, ncurses

I'm sorry for the long question, but I wanted to make sure it got the point across.

The thing is, that no matter what I do, when I use a linux-based console application that uses ncurses, via SSH from Windows, is rendered incorrectly.

I have tried changing the encoding of the SSH client, I have tried installing different fonts (that I know contain the characters used by ncurses), but nothing seems to help.

As a reference, this is what is supposed to be displayed:
(This is a connection from Linux machine)
[image: What it should be]

And this is what I get when I connect from Windows (using [Bitvise SSH client](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier)):
[image: Using Bitvise]

Of course, different encoding settings and different font types produce different results, but they all look wrong.
I've also tried using
Using PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) with similar results.

I personally think it's a font problem...
What do you think?

---

**Edit 2013/1/19 12:51am**

I just tried it from my Mac and guess what? It works as expected.
There are some minor glitches, but the output from toilet, [moc](http://moc.daper.net/), [elinks](http://elinks.or.cz/), [libcaca](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca), etc... look just about right:

[image: Using MAC]

---

**Edit 2013/1/19 3:02am**

Well, whatever the problem, it's not affecting Haiku!

[image: Using Haiku]

---

**Edit 2013/1/19 3:02am**

Eureka!
The problem? The font, just as I suspected.

After trying a countless set of fonts I've finally found one that is capable of properly rendering an SSH session where an application uses ncurses!

The font is the [DejaVu fonts](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dejavu/?source=dlp).
Unfortunately, installing them is not enough; to make these fonts available on the Windows' command prompt you will need to either [manually edit the registry](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stupid-geek-tricks-enable-more-fonts-for-the-windows-command-prompt/) or, if you prefer, use this little app I created: [Command Prompt Fonts](http://whenimbored.xfx.net/2013/01/enabling-additional-command-prompt-fonts/).

Whatever method you use, once you have assigned this font to the Windows' command prompt, you should be able to properly emulate xterm:

[image: Windows with DejaVu fonts]

Comment: Try to change the option "Use Background Colour to erase screen." in PuTTy (options)->(Terminal)

In the server:
export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1

Comment: @duskwuff: Yes. I said so in the OP.

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña: That doesn't seem to make any difference.
Here's a screenshot using [PuTTY](http://software.xfx.net/stackoverflow/terminal_emulation/putty_01.png)